# How can I use Code Engineering Diagrams in EA?

Tags: diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm looking around the New Diagram in version 9.3 of the sparx system enterprise architect.
UML Structural, UML Behavioral, Extended, ArcGIS, BPMN etc.. There is a lot of Diagram.
By the way, what is the Code Engineering Diagram?
There are many programming languages such as ActionScript, C, and C++ as the Diagram Types. There are a total of 10 types, but I don't know the difference even if I create them. It's not even in the user guide.
https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/modeling_basics/manageviews.html

https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/software_engineering/codeengineering.html

What is Code Engineering Diagrams?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Version 9.3??? That is a really old version.  Maybe it's time for an upgrade.

Comment: That is an MDG to the left. The diagram types are to the right. They are stereotyped from the MDG with according tool sets. I'd guess they are just class diagrams.

Comment: P.S. Don't let you get blinded by all the bells and whistles mounted on EA. Use only what you can identify and safely ignore the rest.